# Apache POI xlsx read, cell with # value - error unexpected cell type(5)

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

Could you hepl me with such issue.

I need to read each cell as String value. In this case I am using appache poi lib. and such method for normilizing each cell:

```
String getNormilizedCell(Cell cell){
return new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell);}
```

But when In .xlsx file I faced with such value:

**|#N/A|#N/A|...|...|...**

I am getting error **[Unexpected Cell type (5)]** and I don't know how to handle this. In google I can't find necessary information.

Comment: change your excel cell datatype to "general"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DataFormatter` class only handles `CELL_TYPE_FORMULA`, `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`, `CELL_TYPE_STRING`, `CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN`, and `CELL_TYPE_BLANK`.  It doesn't handle [`CELL_TYPE_ERROR`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#CELL_TYPE_ERROR), which is `5`.

You'll have to work around this by first detecting the error cell type and then handling it specially, referring to the [error cell value codes](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ErrorConstants.html):

```
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR) {
    byte errorValue = cell.getErrorCellValue();
    switch(errorValue) {
    case ERROR_DIV_0:
        return "#DIV/0!";
    case ERROR_NA:
        return "#N/A";
    case ERROR_NAME:
        return "#NAME?";
    case ERROR_NULL:
        return "#NULL!";
    case ERROR_NUM:
        return "#NUM!";
    case ERROR_REF:
        return "#REF!";
    case ERROR_VALUE:
        return "#VALUE!";
    default:
        return "Unknown error value: " + errorValue + "!";
    }
} else {
    return new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell);
}
```

Comment: It does handle CELL_TYPE_ERROR now... :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade your copy of Apache POI!

As of [r1537552](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1537552) DataFormatter is now happy to format Error cells for you. It'll give you back the error string that Excel displays, using the [FormulaError constants](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaError.html)

Comment: It is best to add the ability to handle error types in the Apache POI codebase itself, but what a way to make an answer obsolete!

Comment: How do I pull down this revision in maven? I'm using 3.10beta2 and it doesn't have it.

Comment: Either grab a nightly snapshot, or wait a few days for 3.10 final

Comment: It can still throw an error when evaluating the formula, eg. if you have `=xxx()` in a cell. Excel displays `#NAME?` but we get a "Don't know how to evaluate name 'xxx'" runtime exception.

Comment: @PhiLho It should work fine for all kinds of error cells. If you've found a case where it doesn't, you'll want to [report an Apache POI bug](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI) along with a testcase that shows it!

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Gagravarr, DataFormatter handles most errors now (I use poi-3.11-beta2). But, as said in my comment, some formula errors can still throw exceptions.

For example, when evaluating a formula like `=xxx()` when xxx isn't a real function, Excel displays `#NAME?` but we get a "Don't know how to evaluate name 'xxx'" runtime exception.

Fortunately, it is simple to handle:

```
public String readCellValue(Cell cell)
{
    switch (cell.getCellType())
    {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
        return "(blank)";
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
        return String.valueOf(cell.getErrorCellValue());
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
        return readFormattedCellValue(cell);
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        return String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        return cell.getStringCellValue();
    default:
        return "Unknown type!";
    }
}

public String readFormattedCellValue(Cell cell)
{
    try
    {
        return formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e)
    {
        return e.getMessage(); // Error from evaluator, for example "Don't know how to evaluate name 'xxx'" if we have =xxx() in cell
    }
}
```

For the record, `formatter` and `evaluator` are created like in the convert to CSV example:

```
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file))
    {
        // Open the workbook and then create the FormulaEvaluator and
        // DataFormatter instances that will be needed to, respectively,
        // force evaluation of formulae found in cells and create a
        // formatted String encapsulating the cells contents.
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        formatter = new DataFormatter(true);
    }
```

For some unknown reason, the `WorkbookFactory` lives only in the poi-ooml-3.11-beta2.jar, not in the poi-3.11-beta2.jar one.

Comment: WorkbookFactory creates both HSSF and XSSF workbooks, so has to live in the OOXML jar so it can reference XSSF

Answer (score 0):

```
I too faced the same error while working on Spring batch insert excel data to DB.

I was using spring-batch-excel version 0.5.0 and poi 3.12

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-excel</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

Once Updated to spring-batch-excel version 1.0.1 and poi 3.17, It was resolved.

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.kumarpankaj18</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-excel</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
     </dependency>
```

Note: Even poi 5.0.0 didn't work , I have to use 3.17 only