# How to edit org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatCellValue class in Eclipse with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-poi

Hi I'm trying to implement the toCSV example here:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ToCSV.java

And, I'm using maven to pull in dependencies. Here's a snippet from my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-beta2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
```

And using `maven eclipse:eclipse` all my jar files get pulled into the project.

But, I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected celltype (5)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatCellValue(DataFormatter.java:833)
```

Even though I read in some other SO questions that this was fixed:
[Apache POI xlsx read, cell with # value - error unexpected cell type(5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711603/apache-poi-xlsx-read-cell-with-value-error-unexpected-cell-type5)

Still, I would add in some error handling to the DataFormatter class but I can't get into it. Eclipse says: (screenshot)
[image]

And I don't know how to get to it.

So MY QUESTION is how to I edit this class? Or, am I to assume that the jar files are not actually part of my project but just linked to - and stored in the .m2 folder? Because I would like very much to have them copied into my project folder so that I can make this a web job on a server somewhere...

Comment: Is there a problem with jar version

Comment: Don't you need to tell maven to fetch you the source version too?