# ExcelReader workbook.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK) is not working

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I am trying to read excel file(xls) file using apache poi. In that, during read row if a cell is missing (cellIterator) is skipping that cell and putting the next value to different header.

A  B  C

1  2  3

4  blank   6

In above case it is putting 6 in 'B' column at blank cell and i need B as blank String.

```
`package com.howtodoinjava.demo.poi;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class ReadExcelDemo {

    Integer rowNum;
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook;
    HSSFSheet sheet;
    FileInputStream file;

    public ReadExcelDemo(File file1) throws IOException{
         this.file = new FileInputStream(file1);

        // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        this.workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        workbook.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

        // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
     this.sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        for(int i =0;i<5;i++) {
            List<String> rowData = new ReadExcelDemo(new File(
                    "howtodoinjava_demo_xls.xls")).readRow();
            System.out.println(rowData);
        }

    }

    private List<String> readRow() throws IOException {
        List<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Iterate through each rows one by one
            rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            if (getNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                // For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    // Check the cell type and format accordingly
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        rowData.add(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        rowData.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        rowData.add("");
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            rowNum++;
            close();


        return rowData;
    }

    private void close() throws IOException {
        file.close();
    }

    private boolean getNext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (null == rowNum) {
            rowNum = 0;
        }
        return rowIterator.hasNext();
    }
}
`
```

This is the code snippet. I tried       workbook.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK); but it is not working.
Any suggestion why it is happening ??

Comment: Can you post your code based on using the missing cell policy?

Comment: @Gagravarr This is the same code snippet I am using missing cell policy.I was modifying it read row by row

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI Documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: @Gagravarr- Thanks.I have read that documentation,but i am using row iterator and celliterator and while debugging I am getting at `Row row = rowIterator.next(); `  `row` has not that index cell when it is blank it is skipping that cell to include.Moreover I have openoffice install on my system but the file is excel workbook. Can there be any chances that it is affecting this.

Comment: You might want to go and re-read that page then - it's quite clear that if you want to get all rows (not just those with data in), you need to use the alternate iteration method by row/cell index

Answer (score 1):

I have used iterator for row to read the row one by one,making the rowIterator class level and then using for loop to iterate over columns and to take the full control over row data and set the policy to 'create null as blank'.

```
final Row row = this.sheet.getRow(rowNum);

if (null != row) {

    int lastColumn = row.getLastCellNum();
    // Removing cellIterator as it was not supporting
    // MissingCellPolicy and doing the column iteration through for
    // loop
    for (int cn = Constants.EMPTY_INT; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(cn, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            addNumericCell(rowData, cell);
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            rowData.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            rowData.add(Constants.EMPTY_STRING);
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Useful link for [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator).

Answer (score 0):

Simplified code which works using POI 3.10. Below code return sheet data as List and works for Cell having NULL values.

```
/**
     * Read XLSx and return sheet data as List
     * 
     * @param inputFile
     * @param sheetNo
     * @return
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static List<String> readXlsxAsList(File inputFile, int sheetNo) throws FileNotFoundException,
            IOException {

        List<String> sheetAsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        /**
         * Get workbook
         */
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        /**
         * Get sheet
         */
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNo);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        /**
         * Iterate Rows
         */
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int col = 0; col < row.getLastCellNum(); col++) {
                /**
                 * Create cell to force as BLANK when NULL
                 */
                Cell cell = row.getCell(col, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                /**
                 * Force cell type as String
                 */
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                /**
                 * Add to buffer
                 */
                sb.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + "|");
            }
            /**
             * Add buffer to list
             */
            sheetAsList.add(sb.toString());
        }
        return sheetAsList;
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong on two levels. Firstly, setting the cell type to get it as a string [is explicitly documented as not the right thing to do](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType(int)), and your code will silently skip missing cells without adding blank entries [as per the iterating docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)

Answer (score 0):

```
Similar to issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711603/apache-poi-xlsx-read-cell-with-value-error-unexpected-cell-type5/68892155#68892155

This issue also got resolved using the same logic.
  
  I too faced the same error while working on Spring batch insert excel data to DB.
    
    I was using spring-batch-excel version 0.5.0 and poi 3.12
    
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-excel</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    
    Once Updated to spring-batch-excel version 1.0.1 and poi 3.17, It was resolved.
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kumarpankaj18</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-excel</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
         </dependency>
```