# NullPointerException when accessing a cell with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read an Excel file with Apache POI. 
My goal is to get the cells 2 & 3 from every row and place them into an array. In some rows cell number 3 is empty (I am not talking about EMPTY, NULL or BLANK). Just empty if you check them in Excel.

Some of those empty cells (not all) cause the NullPonterException: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException**. It happens when trying to get the cell value or the cell type. I have the impression that there is no cell at that location.

At the same time if I do `row.createCell(2).setCellType(1);` for that specific row the program continues until next cell of this type. That is the only workaround (that I could find) to continue reading cells from next rows.

Could you please help me understand how to identify these cells (with code) and put my workaround in place so I can continue reading till the end of the file?

This is the code:

```
static ArrayList<String> getFirstFile() throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fileIn = null;

    ArrayList <String> namesFirstFile = new ArrayList <String>();
    String folderPath = "C:\\";
    String indivList1 = "filename.xls";

    fileIn = new FileInputStream(folderPath+indivList1);
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fileIn);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    int rowNumber = 6; //skipping the first 6 rows as irrelevant
    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";

    while(row.getCell(0).getCellType() == 0) {
        lastName = row.getCell(1).toString();
        firstName = row.getCell(2).toString();

        namesFirstFile.add((rowNumber-6), (lastName + " " + firstName));
        rowNumber++;
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the [Row.MissingCellPolicy](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html):

- `static Row.MissingCellPolicy     CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK`

  > A new, blank cell is created for missing cells.
- `static Row.MissingCellPolicy     RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL`

  > Missing cells are returned as null, as are blank cells
- `static Row.MissingCellPolicy     RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK`

  > Missing cells are returned as null, Blank cells are returned as normal

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220489/excelreader-workbook-setmissingcellpolicyrow-create-null-as-blank-is-not-worki) has a good discussion on the topic.

Comment: This line worked: firstName = row.getCell(2, row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getStringCellValue(); Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You have to check the presence of that cell. Remember if a row is present doesn't mean that all the cells are present. If that particular cell is not present doing get operations will throw you null pointer error, but create cell will not throw an error because it creates that cell in that particular row. You can do a dot operator on that cell object only if it exists.

For Example:

If the cell at 3rd position is present this will work:

`row1.getCell(2).getStringCellValue(); // if the value is of string type`

else you have check using if and create that cell if needed.

```
// This checks if the cell is present or it'll return null if the cell
// is not present (it won't check the value in cell)
if (row1.getCell(2) != null)
{
   row1.createCell(2);
}
```

If that cell is not present and your only objective is to get the value, you can set a default value in your array.

These 2 lines won't work because it'll convert the cell object to string but not the content of it:

```
lastName = row.getCell(1).toString();
firstName = row.getCell(2).toString();
```

You have to change it to:

```
lastName = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
firstName = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
```

You need not do this when you don't have any value in that cell:

```
if (row.getCell(2) != null)
{
    row.createCell(2);
}
firstName = row.getCell(2).toString();
```

change this to:

```
if (row.getCell(2) != null)
{
    firstName = row.getCell(2); // your other operations
} else {
    firstname = "default value"; // your other operations
}
```

There's no need of doing a get cell value just when you have created a cell without setting a value.

You have to use `row.createCell(2);` only when you are setting a value to the cell. Here you don't have a value in it.

Comment: Tried! Did not work. Result same as before. I guess it is because the  if checks if the value is null, not if the cell exists.

Comment: Thanks for posting anyway!

Comment: Then your row object is null. Can you show you're code and the line where you are getting null pointer exception. I can help you fix this

Comment: substituting .toString(); with .getStringCellValue(); does not change anything. I am using .println to verify what is processed. It stops at the same line as before. The nullpointer is at the line firstName = row.getCell(2).toString(); OR firstName = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue(); Does not matter which one I use.

Comment: Thank you Tejus P for your willingness to help and your time. I appreciate it, Problem solved.